# Where clause returning all rows and not specific rows for Count()

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, count, where-clause

I have a select statement that derives a count based on the number of patients who have either had a doctor visit for a 'procedure', an 'observation' or a 'condition' contained in a stored procedure. I am using 'procedure', 'observation' and 'condition' as optional parameters.  'procedure','condition' and 'observation' are all stored in separate tables. The goal is to calculate a 'numerator' value for number of patients that have a 'procedure', 'observation' or 'condition' in a time period.

It looks like if the same patient has multiple 'procedure', multiple 'observations' or multiple 'conditions', the 'count' is deriving all of those and not for the specific 'numerator' value that is fed into the stored procedure.

```
Parameter declarations: 
@CareSite VARCHAR(1000),       /* where visit occurs */
@AgeStart VARCHAR(10),         /* starting age patient's age falls in */
@AgeEnd VARCHAR(10),           /* ending age patient's age falls in */
@Gender VARCHAR(10),           /* 'men' or 'women'
@Procedure_Numerator VARCHAR(1000)=null,  /* procedure the visit is for */
@Condition_Numerator VARCHAR(1000)=null,  /* condition the visit is for */
@Observation_Numerator VARCHAR(1000)=null /* observation the visit is for */

SELECT statement: 

DECLARE @D1NumVal INT 
    SET @D1NumVal = (SELECT COUNT(*) AS Numerator  
                       FROM SAS2SQL_DenominatorPersonTest DPT
                       JOIN SAS2SQL_DenominatorProcedureTest DPRT
                         ON DPRT.PersonID = DPT.PersonID 
                       JOIN SAS2SQL_DenominatorConditionTest DCT
                         ON DCT.Person_ID = DPT.PersonID
                       JOIN SAS2SQL_DenominatorObservationsTest DOT
                         ON DOT.PersonID = DPT.PersonID
                      WHERE DPT.D1 = 1
                        AND DPT.Age >= @AgeStart AND DPT.Age <= @AgeEnd
                        AND (@Procedure_Numerator IS NOT NULL AND 
                             DPT.CareSiteName = @CareSite AND DPT.Wave = 
                             @Wave 
                             AND DPT.Gender = @Gender AND 
                             DPRT.ProcudureSourceValue = 
                             @Procedure_Numerator)
                         OR (@Condition_Numerator IS NOT NULL AND 
                             DPT.CareSiteName = @CareSite AND DPT.Wave =    
                             @Wave 
                         AND DPT.Gender = @Gender AND 
                             DCT.X_Condition_Source_Desc = 
                             @Condition_Numerator)
                          OR (@Observation_Numerator IS NOT NULL AND 
                             DPT.CareSiteName = @CareSite AND DPT.Wave = 
                             @Wave 
                             AND DPT.Gender = @Gender AND 
                             DOT.ObservationSourceValue = 
                             @Observation_Numerator))
```

I tried using the 'CASE WHEN' approach but what I have above has returned results that are closer to what I am trying to generate.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to add parentheses as `AND` is evaluated before `OR`, after the 2nd `AND` and a final one.

This seems to match your description:

```
DECLARE @D1NumVal INT 
    SET @D1NumVal = (SELECT COUNT(*) AS Numerator  
                       FROM SAS2SQL_DenominatorPersonTest DPT
                       JOIN SAS2SQL_DenominatorProcedureTest DPRT
                         ON DPRT.PersonID = DPT.PersonID 
                       JOIN SAS2SQL_DenominatorConditionTest DCT
                         ON DCT.Person_ID = DPT.PersonID
                       JOIN SAS2SQL_DenominatorObservationsTest DOT
                         ON DOT.PersonID = DPT.PersonID
                      WHERE DPT.D1 = 1
                        AND DPT.Age >= @AgeStart AND DPT.Age <= @AgeEnd
                        AND((@Procedure_Numerator IS NOT NULL AND 
                             DPT.CareSiteName = @CareSite AND DPT.Wave = 
                             @Wave 
                             AND DPT.Gender = @Gender AND 
                             DPRT.ProcudureSourceValue = 
                             @Procedure_Numerator)
                         OR (@Condition_Numerator IS NOT NULL AND 
                             DPT.CareSiteName = @CareSite AND DPT.Wave =    
                             @Wave 
                         AND DPT.Gender = @Gender AND 
                             DCT.X_Condition_Source_Desc = 
                             @Condition_Numerator)
                          OR (@Observation_Numerator IS NOT NULL AND 
                             DPT.CareSiteName = @CareSite AND DPT.Wave = 
                             @Wave 
                             AND DPT.Gender = @Gender AND 
                             DOT.ObservationSourceValue = 
                             @Observation_Numerator)))
```

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion, dnoeth. It looks like that worked. I am only seeing results now containing the appropriate counts per wave. The visits occur between start and end dates for each wave, which is roughly a 3 month period of time. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hmmm...it looks like there is still a problem after testing further with other numerator values in regards to the count being off. I will work on this more today and see if I can resolve it...